# Get Form elements with js in coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the elements of a form in order to use them later to create an ajax call to a function.

In detail, I have a form that looks something like this: (Only mine is about 6 times bigger)

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/> <br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="M"> Male<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="F"> Female<br />

<input type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" value="Set Variables" onClick="setSession();">
</form>
```

I need to write a function that will display the names or ids of the form elements with their values or at least a number in an array so I would know that element[0] is equal to my name form variable.

I wrote a few different versions of the function but I ended up lost and even more confused and this is where I need help.

After I have the variables set I need to use them for my ajax call which will look something like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'setSessions.cfc?method=setSession',
    method:"POST",
    data: {name: name,
           email: email,
           gender: gender}
});
```

which it will call the setSessions component that will set my session variables.

Comment: You do not know how to use getElementById to get the value? Or use basic jQuery to get an element?

Comment: I do know how to do that but I believe what i am trying to do is much more complicated than that. To be honest I may just over thought the whole thing. The form above its just a sample, my form has around 20 fields and I don't feel like writing getElementById 20 times.

Comment: Maybe you should have put that in your question to start out.

Comment: You are right, I apologize for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/GeVcX/)

You can get your form data like this.

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();

$.ajax({
    url:'setSessions.cfc?method=setSession',
    method:"POST",
    data: formData
});
```

If you want to access individual element , you can do this,

```
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
```

Comment: Your answer could work with what I need to accomplish. One more question though, is there a way to access each individual element separately? Like after you set `var formData = $('form').serialize();`  is there a way to do something like `formData.name` or whatever in case I need to access a specific variable only?

Comment: Thanks Mohammad but this is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Geo do serializeArray instead of serialize. it will result [{ name: 'name', value: 'value' }, ...] array.modify it

Answer (score 3):

Try using serialize (or serializeArray) method of jquery:

```
form.serialize();
```